# edit image src using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to edit src attribute of all my images. I actually want to remove remove "\test" from all the images src. I have tried replace and src.replace in jquery, but it didn't work out can. Please help how to do that.

```
$("img").each(function(){
            var srcVar = this.attr('src');
            this.attr('src', "http://www.abc.gr"+srcVar);
        });
```

Comment: +srcVar.split("/test")[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    var srcVar = $(this).attr('src').replace("/test", "");;
    $(this).attr('src', srcVar);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
$("img").each(function(){

    // get the current source, replace the test string
    var srcVar = this.attr('src').replace('/test', '');

    // apply it back
    $(this).attr('src', srcVar);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out...

```
$("img").each(function(){
    var srcVar = $(this).attr('src');
    srcVar = srcVar.replace("/test", "");
    $(this).attr('src', srcVar);
});
```